# ¿Es hora de almacenar procedimientos y crear sinónimos?

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, sinónimos-de-etiquetas

Tenemos dos etiquetas equivalentes en el sitio: [stored-procedure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stored-procedure) y  [procedimiento-almacenado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedimiento-almacenado) que seguramente deberían ser combinadas en la misma y hechas sinónimas.

Pero la cosa es que no sé cuál debería apuntar a cual:

- Por un lado, como somos Stack Overflow en Español, pienso que lo correcto sería que [procedimiento-almacenado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedimiento-almacenado) prevaleciera sobre la otra etiqueta...
- Pero por otro, [stored-procedure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stored-procedure) tiene 10 veces más preguntas (54 vs 5 al escribir este post), es bastante más corto, y se podría considerar más próximo a la nomenclatura de SQL (aunque realmente es `procedure` sin el stored).

La cosa es que no puedo solicitar ponerlos como sinónimos porque no tengo suficiente reputación en ninguna de las etiquetas, así que necesito la opinión y ayuda de la comunidad.

¿Se debería crear un sinónimo? ¿De cuál a cuál? ¿Quién puede pedirlo?

Comment: Mis disculpas, no se me ocurría ningún juego de palabras mejor para el título de la pregunta :S

Comment: Hacemos una votación?

Comment: @Mariano Para esa en particular, no hace falta, ya hice el sinónimo. Te invito a mirar la gran cantidad de resultados en [la búsqueda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22procedimiento+almacenado%22)... Definitivamente es un término que usa la gente.

Comment: @ArtEze Así como también "stored procedure" devuelve 74 resultados y "SP" 85... Creo que no solamente depende del uso sino de lo que los profesionales de la comunidad consideren correcto. Así como Álvaro no está seguro en su publicación, yo tampoco. Estoy inclinado a utilizar [tag:stored-procedure] (el término que uso), pero no puedo decidirme si no optar por la opción en español... Consideremos que al generar el sinónimo, al escribir una, aparecería la otra como opción.

Comment: @Mariano ok, entonces hacemos la votación... Si la que está en inglés tiene más votos, hago el intercambio. Mientras tanto, queda como maestro [tag:procedimiento-almacenado].

Comment: @ArtEze Gracias por considerarlo. Y se aprecia la velocidad de resolución. Sé que probablemente se opte por el término en español (como en la mayoría de las discusiones que se dieron en Meta), pero no quería dejar de dar lugar a la opinión.

Comment: Me pregunto que opción ranquearea mejor en una búsqueda en google. La verdad que no se la respuesta, pero creo que esa seria la mejor opción. No simplemente elegir por gusto.

Answer (score 10):

Pienso que es mejor que quede como etiqueta maestra: [stored-procedure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stored-procedure).

Answer (score 7):

Pienso que es mejor que quede como etiqueta maestra: [procedimiento-almacenado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedimiento-almacenado).

Answer (score 3):

He creado el sinónimo.

> [procedimiento-almacenado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedimiento-almacenado) (maestro) - [stored-procedure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stored-procedure)

Pero por votación, ahora queda:

> [stored-procedure](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stored-procedure) (maestro) - [procedimiento-almacenado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/procedimiento-almacenado)